# WYSIWYG editor and loaded content trouble

Tags: textarea, ckeditor, loading

I have a wysiwyg editor **ckeditor**. It has a textarea. Okay, everything works fine, but until I'm trying to load content which already has inputs elements (textarea). So, we have:

```
<textarea id="ckeditor">
   ... Loadable content ...
  <textarea id="some_other"></textarea>
</textarea>
```

As you see loadable textarea is closing ckeditor-area, and another content is outside editor. Any suggestions to make another textarea in my ckeditor-area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape it:

```
<textarea>...&lt;/textarea&gt;...</textarea>
```

There are functions for that in every language, e.g. htmlspecialchars in PHP.